# Conditionally declare make_unique only if not provided by STL, otherwise, declare using std::make_unique

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have the following code:

```
namespace notstd{
  // Only Declare this if std::make_unique exists
  using std::make_unique; 
  
  // Only Declare this if std::make_unique DOES NOT exist
  template<class T,class...Args> //
  std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&...args){
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
}
```

I would like the using declaration only declared if std::make_unique is defined (`std::make_unique` did not exist until C++14), otherwise, I would like to define my local version. I believe that this can be accomplished with SFINAE in C++11, but I cannot get it to work. Any advice?

Comment: Can you explain the circumstances by which you believe result in `std::make_unique` not being defined?

Comment: std::make_unique was not added to the standard until C++14. I am working in C++11, but my project may move to C++14 (or later) in the future.

Comment: You're overthinking it. Declare your `nostd::make_unique`. Write the rest of the code to use it. When you're ready to move to C++14, just remove this definition and fix all compilation errors. Depending on how well the code is organized, it might be merely a matter of running search/replace once, against the entire code base: `s/nostd::make_unique/std::make_unique/g`.

Comment: This could help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace, especially `__cplusplus`. You can check `#if __cplusplus > 201103L`

Comment: I hear what you're saying @SamVarshavchik, but say I did want to resolve this with SFINAE. How would I do it?

Comment: @Vinny - I'm with Sam here. If and when `std::make_unique` is available, I really would not like my source full of `nonstd::` when it in fact *is* using the standard version. The code should not lie to the reader. And also, adding extra unused code "just in case" or to be future proof, is often a wasted effort.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing at this point regarding the answer to my specific quandary. I would however still like to know how to solve similar problems with SFINAE for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I would not actually try to do this with SFINAE, *especially* since adding to the `std` namespace is undefined behaviour except for certain limited scenarios like template specialisation - your approach seems to be less specialisation and more creation from scratch :-)

Instead, you could just use the `__cplusplus` macro to conditionally compile code based on the supported level. This is set to `201103` for C++11 and `201402` for C++14, so should be easily usable.

Comment: For more granularity, check `__cpp_lib_make_unique >= 201304`.

Comment: @HTNW Isn't that always true? Isn't `__cpp_lib_make_unique` an alias for 201304? You probably mean `__cplusplus >= __cpp_lib_make_unique`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test#cpp_lib_make_unique

Comment: @jabaa Not if `__cpp_lib_make_unique` isn't defined. In C++11, a `#if __cpp_lib_make_unique >= 201304` test [will fail](https://godbolt.org/z/W1cqsfc5d). The feature test macros tell you the revision of the feature available in the currently chosen implementation, just like `__cplusplus` tells you the overall current C++ version. They are not just aliases to check `__cplusplus` against.

Comment: @jabaa Actually,  your `__cplusplus >= __cpp_lib_make_unique` is the expression that's always true (except maybe if you have some development version of a compiler?). Either `__cplusplus` indicates ≤C++11 and `__cpp_lib_make_unique` is `0` (the preprocessor is defined to treat undefined macros as `0`) or `__cplusplus` indicates the date C++xy was completed and `__cpp_lib_make_unique` indicates some time at or before that. (I say this in case someone is tempted to try yours.) I.e. the test "is the current C++ version ahead of the current version of some specific feature?" should never fail.

Comment: @HTNW Yes, I thought it's always set. I would go with `#ifdef __cpp_lib_make_unique`

Comment: @jabaa Use `#if` instead: `#if __cpp_lib_make_unique`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why? I've tested with `#ifdef`. It worked for me. What's the difference?

Comment: @jabaa in this case, not much. Examples I've seen use `#if`. `#ifdef` checks if a given *identifier* is defined, regardless of its value. `#if` evaluates an *expression* instead. `#ifdef __cpp_lib_make_unique` is effectively `#if defined(__cpp_lib_make_unique)` whereas `#if __cpp_lib_make_unique` is effectively `#if defined(__cpp_lib_make_unique) && (__cpp_lib_make_unique != 0)`

Comment: How would checking `__cpp_lib_make_unique` work in C++14 and C++17? These feature testing macros were added in C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test.

Answer (score 1):

SFINAE is not the right way to handle this. C++11 and later actually provide a way of telling you whether specific standard language/library features are implemented or not. In this case, you can use the predefined `__cpp_lib_make_unique` macro, which is defined when `std::make_unique()` is implemented, eg:

```
#include <memory>

namespace notstd{

  #if __cpp_lib_make_unique

  // Only Declare this if std::make_unique exists
  using std::make_unique; 

  #else  

  // Only Declare this if std::make_unique DOES NOT exist
  template<class T,class...Args> //
  std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&...args){
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }

  #endif
}
```

See [Feature testing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) and [Library feature-test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/feature_test) on cppreference.com for more details.

Comment: `__cpp_lib_make_unique` was introduced in C++20, so your approach would not work for C++ versions from C++14 that predate C++20.   For those cases, it would be necessary to check language version (e.g. using `__cplusplus`).

Comment: thank you, to both peter and remy. I will use the preprocessor approach recommended here. However, I would still like to know how to make this work via SFINAE from a purely academic standpoint, for similar problems in the future